# How can Web deployed in single server be accessible across multiple network isolated domain? [Nginx/Apache/Gunicorn]

Tags: python, apache, nginx, deployment, architecture

I have a web application that is deployed in one domain. However, there are many users in other isolated network domains say **Domain-1, Domain-2, Domain-3**, etc., The infra setup is of On-Prem type and app deployment is done in the same setup say **Domain-1**.

Constraints:

1. Deployment of WebApp in available network domains is not an option.
2. Network Connectivity in some domains can not be allowed for external communications.

*Currently Flask based WebApp is deployed as a systemctl-service on Ubuntu.*

Considering the Constraints in mind, What are the best options available to achieve accessibility to all users?